# BeagleBone Black HDMI to VGA converter creating problem with the display

Tags: beaglebone-black, vga

I recently bought a BBB and have started setting the initial environment before I start some actual developments. Since, my monitor has a VGA input, I bought a HDMI to VGA converter adapter to interface my BBB to the monitor. However, I am facing a problem i.e.

Problem Scenario : I power my new BBB from an external 5Vdc/1A adapter and then connect the BBB to the monitor using the HDMI to VGA converter. After booting the BBB, the display comes on the monitor for a few minutes and then, some how the display goes off and the screen blacks out (I presume it is to do with the HDMI to VGA adapter).

Has anyone using BBB comer across this problem?, If so could you please detail me on what is creating this issue and how to resolve it. Thank you all in advance!

Between to add, when it was tested with my friends BBB, it worked perfectly fine, but with mine it was giving this problem!.

Regards
~VD

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, which is HDMI -> VGA adapter. You probably need powered one. You can discover this issue while using other boards e.g. MinnowBoard. On monday I am going to test this with such powered adapter and I will let you know.

Comment: Ok and, after a while of searching, I found some resources which might be helpful : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/B51_9eAH9vE and  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=toPYh_VCHvI and http://m-embedded.blogspot.in/2014/12/solved-beaglebone-blacks-hdmi-port.html. Also, check out these links and let me know what do you think?

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NuapbnQAxp4. As I expected, all you need to do is to cut supply wire and add another 2 wires. The problem which appeared is admissive power, so if you have enough space you can mount small radiator to cool down stabilizer.